# Django and database connector problems

Tags: python, django

I have this installed for mysql and django , still I receive an error

-Django                 2.1.3

-mysql-connector-python 8.0.13

-pip                    18.1

-pytz                   2018.7

-setuptools             39.0.1

-virtualenv             16.0.0

-virtualenvwrapper-win  1.2.5

-wheel                  0.32.3

How can I connect to mysql and django with mysql-connector. I still receive an error to install mysqlclient. Is there anything missing. please let me know

Comment: Did you install MySQL...? From what you wrote that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `DATABASES` setting to use the connector backend.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have MySQL installed. follow up here:

But first, check if these tutorials apply for your current OS version! The installation process can be different

example: 
Ubuntu 14, 16 or 18. 
Mac osx 10.12 Sierra, 10.13 High Sierra or 10.14 mojave

Windows:
https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=mysql

Ubuntu:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Mac osx:
https://gist.github.com/operatino/392614486ce4421063b9dece4dfe6c21

With MySQL up and running, log into the interactive session for MySQL

```
mysql -u root -p
```

create your database user

```
CREATE DATABASE myproject CHARACTER SET UTF8;
CREATE USER myprojectuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myproject.* TO myprojectuser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

now in `myproject/myproject/settings.py` apply these changes:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: please accept this answer so it helps people to find the solution easier :)